# SEO URLs and non existant URL redirections with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I defined SEO URLs in .htaccess for each php pages like this:

```
RewriteRule en/english-page1$ page1_en.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule de/german-page1$ page1_de.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule en/english-page2$ page2_en.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule de/german-page2$ page2_de.php [NC,L]
```

so with URL "www.mysite.com/en/english-page1" the page "page1_en.php" is actually loaded correctly (all my .php files are in root directory and there are no "en" or "de" folders physically created)

Now what I need is to define the default pages for "en" and "de" languages, then redirect all non-existent URLs to the default page in each language.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For pages 1 to N use:

```
RewriteRule en/english-page(\d+)$ page$1_en.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule de/german-page(\d+)$ page$1_de.php [NC,L]
```

And add in the end:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/? $1/default-page [R,NC,L]
```

With `en/default-page` and `de/default-page` pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works.
Can I automatically redirect the result to the final URL ("mysite.com/en/english-page1" instead of just "mysite.com/en/")?
Thank you!

Comment: Another problem is that I can add any string after "/en/" (eg. mysite.com/en/asdf), the default page is loaded but the entered wrong URL still visible. Can I force the URL to change to the good one?